# Correct PHP contact form syntax?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am trying to follow a PHP contact form tutorial from [here](https://github.com/bootstrapbay/contact-form/blob/master/index.php)! 
Seems pretty simple and I'm completely new to PHP. However, when running my project, I get so many "Notice" messages and errors!

I managed to fix many of them, by surrounding most variables in issets

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name'];}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){$email = $_POST['email'];}
if(isset($_POST['phone'])){$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
if(isset($_POST['message'])){$message = $_POST['message'];}
if(isset($_POST['human'])){$human = intval($_POST['human']);}
if(isset($_POST['from'])){$from = 'Página Web';}
if(isset($_POST['to'])){$to = 'bla@bla.com';}
if(isset($_POST['name'])){$subject = 'Mensaje de Página Web';}
if(isset($_POST['name'])){$body = "De: $name\n Teléfono: $phone\n E-Mail:   $email\n Mensaje:\n $message";}
```

However, I still get these pesky notifications:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK3J5.png)

Line 16 is:

```
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
```

And the rest are for example found in lines like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
</div>
```

even though these variables are declared on the top.

How can I fix the top notice and the "undeclared variable" errors? I've tried looking up other tutorials, but they seem to do the same, ignoring the issets (and making my Netbeans upset and full of warnings!) and using the same syntax.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don`t seem to have a form element with the NAME 'submit'

Comment: the first time you hit the page `$errMessage` is not defined, so you get an error

Comment: My button's name, type and id (<input>) is submit.

Comment: @Dagon Thanks! That covered all errors below the inputs! Now just need to figure out the submit error on the top. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you load the form, `$_POST` will not have anything populated. Try changing

```
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
```

to determine if the form was in fact submitted and continue accordingly.

Comment: I'm not a smart man, I surrounded everything with issets, but not that specific if. Thank you so much, that did the trick. And thank you all the others for helping out too! I'll check your comment as answer as soon as the site allows me to! :) Thank you so much

Comment: We've **all** been there. Trust me. Best wishes!